# reference component variable from ng-content

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular2-ngcontent

I have the following piece of markup:

```
<group-header [isOpen]="true">
    <div *ngIf="isOpen">{{'PRICE' | resource}}</div>
</group-header>
```

group-header's template looks like this:

```
<div (click)="toggleGroups($event);">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

isOpen is defined in my group-header component like this:

```
@Input()
set isOpen(value: boolean) {
    this._isOpen = value;
}

get isOpen() {
    return this._isOpen;
}
```

Apparently I cannot reference isOpen the way I want to (or at all for that matter) as my 'PRICE' resource never displays.

Is there a way to have my ng-content rendered content display conditionally based on a field on my component?

Hope this all makes sense... if not please ask

EDIT: Added setter as per @PierreDuc's comment :-)

Comment: do you also have a setter in your `group-header` component for `isOpen`?

Comment: Yes. Updated question :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a template variable to reference the `GroupHeader` component:

```
<group-header [isOpen]="true" #gh>
    <div *ngIf="gh.isOpen">{{'PRICE' | resource}}</div>
</group-header>
```

Comment: Ah, of course. Silly me. The `isOpen` references the parent component of `group-header`, not the group-header itself. Adding `gh.` makes sure you reference the group-header component

Comment: Glad to hear. Wasn't sure this is what you're looking for.